# How do I add additional properties to a text box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, wpf-controls

I'm trying to add a couple of custom properties to textboxes in my application , it will help me reduce the lines of code needed drastically..

C# Code for adding the property

```
class HorizonTextBoxExt:TextBox
{
    public HorizonTextBoxExt() : base() { }

    public bool BoundToDataGrid
    {
        get { return (bool)this.GetValue(BoundToDataGridProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(BoundToDataGridProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundToDataGridProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "BoundToDataGrid",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(HorizonTextBoxExt),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(false)
    );
}
```

> "Error    3   The attachable property 'BoundToDataGrid' was not found in
>   type HorizonTextBoxExt'.

is the error I get in the xaml wind of the wpf designer

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:Local ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="63" Margin="90,47,0,0"       TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225" Local:HorizonTextBoxExt.BoundToDataGrid="true" />

           </Grid>
     </Window>
```

Comment: Did you perhaps intend to create [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? At least the property usage in XAML makes me think so.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox /* ... */ Local:HorizonTextBoxExt.BoundToDataGrid="true" />

</Grid>
```

with this:

```
<Grid>
    <Local:HorizonTextBoxExt /* ... */ BoundToDataGrid="true" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the redundant code from your example. If you want you can change it back via the edit button under your answer.

Comment: That's fine :) Thanks @Default